# Problem with running Excel VBA macros, despite having them enabled in trust centre

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "^ ", "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}"
End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "^ "
End Sub
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jUV9AJH9xk-TLMblmfnj9yxek8hpZ8ck/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to bind CTRL + SPACE to run input SHIFT & SPACE, followed by ALT & i & r and then UP & DOWN when I am within a particular sheet.

I'm getting this error message when I use the CTRL + SPACE key combination when it triggers the OnKey event:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoC3q.png)

[Security settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxMcw.png)

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey): "Runs a specified procedure when a particular key or key combination is pressed." `"+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}"` is not a procedure.

Comment: Even if I include the keys in a standard module, I am still having the same problem with the error about macros.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gdqF_5QawmIGJwMtPvWJURjqc6lY6wqp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ShaunHill It cant run the macro, because a string of keys is not a macro. Its looking through your public code modules trying to find a macro with the name "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}" and not finding anything. You have to make a sub or function that `OnKey` can find within your code modules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code into a sub, and then tell `.OnKey` to refer to that sub whenever the keys are pressed.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^ ", "Sheet2.DoStuff"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^ "
End Sub

Public Sub DoStuff()
    Application.SendKeys "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

In my example code, this is happening on "Sheet2" which is why I put "Sheet2.DoStuff". Change this to match the name of your code module and the name of your sub/function.

Comment: So in the public sub it has to refer to SendKeys?

Comment: `SendKeys` is the method that VBA uses to emulate keyboard keys. Just "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}" on its own means nothing, but `SendKeys` turns that into a series of button presses.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

So, the macro works (sendskeys) when I run it manually. However, if I try to run it by pressing CTRL + SPACE, it comes up with the error "Cannot run the macro...The macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled". I've already shown in the images I linked that Trust Centre already has them enabled.

Can you try my workbook linked and tell me if you get the same behavior?

Comment: @ShaunHill I'm not able to open your workbook from my work computer, but I am guessing that the problem is how you have written the name of the sub/function. Put the code into the code module of the sheet. And then find the [CodeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) of the worksheet. Then prepend that onto the name of the sub/function like `Sheet2.DoStuff`. In that string, `Sheet2` is not the Worksheet Name, but the `CodeName`.

Comment: I've done the following:

Added this code to Sheet1:
<br/>
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "^ ", "Insert"
End Sub
<br/>
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "^ "
End Sub
<br/>
Sub Fill()
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Trend:=True
End Sub 
<br/>
Then created a module called "Insert" (also renamed in module properties to the same).
<br/>
Public Sub Insert()
Application.SendKeys "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}"
End Sub

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @ShaunHill Try `Application.OnKey "^ ", "Sheet1.Insert"` but aside from that, Insert is a bad name for a sub because it is already in use for `Range.Insert`. Try to rename it something more unique.

Comment: Adding the sub to the sheet instead as you suggested:  

`Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()  
Application.OnKey "^ ", "Sheet1.NewRow"  
End Sub  
  
Public Sub NewRow()  
Application.SendKeys "+( )%(ir){UP}{DOWN}"  
End Sub  
  
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()  
Application.OnKey "^ "  
End Sub  

Sub Fill()  
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _  
        Trend:=True  
End Sub`  

It's still not running. It's really annoying when it does run properly when it's done manually without the binding.

Comment: @ShaunHill Hopefully someone else is able to provide an answer. Unfortunately I don't have any more advice to give. You should update your post with your new code and more details about the situation. Hopefully you will get an answer from someone more experienced.